# SQL IN and AND clause output

Tags: sql

I have written one small query like below. It is giving me output.

```
select user_id 
from table tf
where tf.function_id in ('1001051','1001060','1001061')
```

but when i am running query like below it is showing 0 out put.however i have verified manually we have user_id's where all the 3 function_id's are present.

```
select user_id 
from table tf
where tf.function_id='1001051' 
      and 
      tf.function_id='1001060' 
      and 
      tf.function_id='1001061'
```

it looks very simple to use AND clause. However i am not gettng desired output. AM i doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use OR instead of AND. None of the rows will meet all three criteria together, a pre-requisite for AND.

Comment: As i mentioned, all the three function ID's exists for one single user. I need to display those User ID's where all the 3 function ID's exists. Using OR will give me output of any single existance of function ID.

Comment: So basically, you want to display the user id's in tf with all three function_id's. Definitely, AND is still not the way. A literal translation of the IN clause is to use OR. But I think I get what yiu are trying to achieve here. I would go with Gordon Linoff's answer. It gives users with all three function id, thanks to the having count clause.

Comment: thanks.. i am trying with that way.. Actual query which of mine is..  select tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias, tf.function_nm
from t_usr tu, t_usr_function tuf, t_function tf
where tu.usr_id = tuf.usr_id
and tuf.function_id = tf.function_id
and tf.function_id='1001051' and tf.function_id='1001060' and tf.function_id='1001061'

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you want to do?

```
select tf.user_id
from table tf
where tf.function_id in ('1001051', '1001060', '1001061')
group by tf.user_id
having count(distinct tf.function_id) = 3;
```

This returns users that have all three functions.

EDIT:

This is the query in your comment:

```
select tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias, tf.function_nm
from t_usr tu, t_usr_function tuf, t_function tf
where tu.usr_id = tuf.usr_id and tuf.function_id = tf.function_id and
      tf.function_id = '1001051' and tf.function_id = '1001060' and tf.function_id = '1001061' ;
```

First, you should learn proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

I think the query you want is:

```
select tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias
from t_usr tu join
     t_usr_function tuf
     on tu.usr_id = tuf.usr_id 
where tuf.function_id in ('1001051', '1001060', '1001061')
group by tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias
having count(distinct tuf.function_id) = 3;
```

This doesn't give you the function name.  I'm not sure why you need such detail if all three functions are there for each "user" (or at least dealer/user alias combination).  And, the original question doesn't request this level of detail.

Comment: The above answer assumes that `user_id, function_id` is unique.

Comment: As i mentioned, all the three function ID's exists for one single user. I need to display those User ID's where all the 3 function ID's exists. Using OR will give me output of any single existence of function ID.

Comment: Actual query is below.. where i am extracting from 3 tables. user Id and function_id is unique too.But i tried your approach. didnt succeed..

select tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias, tf.function_nm
from t_usr tu, t_usr_function tuf, t_function tf
where tu.usr_id = tuf.usr_id
and tuf.function_id = tf.function_id
and tf.function_id='1001051' and tf.function_id='1001060' and tf.function_id='1001061'

Comment: @user3688579 . . . Your query has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: tuf.function_id and tf.function_nm name are same. So i just modified like below.

select tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias, tf.function_nm
from t_usr tu join
     t_usr_function tuf
     on tu.usr_id = tuf.usr_id 
where tuf.function_id in ('1001051', '1001060', '1001061')
group by tu.dealer_id, tu.usr_alias, tf.function_nm
having count(distinct tuf.function_id) = 3;

Answer (score 1):

Using 'AND' clause mean that the query should satisfy all of the conditions.
in your case, you need to return either when the `function_id='1001051'` OR `function_id='1001060'`.
So in brief you need to replace the `AND` by `OR`.

```
select user_id from table tf
where tf.function_id='1001051' OR tf.function_id='1001060' OR tf.function_id='1001061'
```

Thats what the `IN` do, it compares with either of them.

Comment: As i mentioned, all the three function ID's exists for one single user. I need to display those User ID's where all the 3 function ID's exists. Using OR will give me output of any single existence of function ID.

Comment: yes but it exists as different records. you use `and` to merge conditions, like on different columns

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in the comment, AND is not the right operator since all three conditions together will not be met. Use OR instead,

```
select user_id from table tf
where tf.function_id='1001051' OR tf.function_id='1001060' OR tf.function_id='1001061'
```

Answer (score 1):

If **all** of these things are true:

```
tf.function_id='1001051'
tf.function_id='1001060'
tf.function_id='1001061'
```

Then simple algebra tells us this must also be true:

```
'1001051'='1001060'='1001061'
```

Since that clearly can't ever be true, your SQL statement's `where` clause will always resolve to false.

What you want to say is that **any** of those conditions is true (which is equivalent to `in`), which means you need to use `or`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM   table tf
WHERE      tf.function_id = '1001051'
        OR tf.function_id = '1001060'
        OR tf.function_id = '1001061'
```

---

The where clause applies to each row returned by the query. In order to gather data across rows, you either need to join the table to itself enough times to create a single row that satisfies the condition you're looking for or use aggregate functions to consolidate several rows into a single row.

Self-join solution:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM   table tf1
       JOIN table tf2 ON tf1.user_id = tf2.user_id
       JOIN table tf3 ON tf1.user_id = tf3.user_id
WHERE      tf1.function_id = '1001051'
       AND tf2.function_id = '1001060'
       AND tf3.function_id = '1001061'
```

Aggregate solution:

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     table tf
WHERE    tf.function_id IN ('1001051', '1001060', '1001061')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   COUNT (DISTINCT tf.function_id) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the value to be three different values at the same time.  A better use would be to use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
select user_id from table tf
where tf.function_id='1001051' or tf.function_id='1001060' or tf.function_id='1001061'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as this link [SQL IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
select function_id, user_id from table tf
where tf.function_id in ('1001051','1001060','1001061')
```